# How to implement syscall in XV6

Tags: operating-system, kernel, system-calls, xv6, userspace

I have this assignment:

Implement a syscall that returns information about the current process (e.g. its process ID
and state). Think about who is responsible for allocating the memory that contains the
process information that will be returned and how it can be freed again after use (if it needs
to be freed).

But im stuck at making the syscall produce any meaningful output...

This is the code in my kernel space, implemented in sysproc.c:

```
uint64
sys_getprocinfo(struct proc* user_pi)
{
  struct proc *curproc = myproc();
  struct proc pi;

  acquire(&curproc->lock);
  pi.pid = curproc->pid;
  pi.state = curproc->state;
  release(&curproc->lock);

  if(copyout(curproc->pagetable, (uint64)user_pi, (char*)&pi, sizeof(pi)) < 0)
        return -1;

  return 0;
}
```

And the user space program in user/getproc.c

```
#include "user.h"
//#include "kernel/types.h"


//blueprint for proc info strukturen
struct proc {
        int pid;
        int state;
        //evt annet?
};

//state nr tilsvarer nr i array her:
//enum procstate { UNUSED, USED, SLEEPING, RUNNABLE, RUNNING, ZOMBIE}

int main(void)

{
  //info blir av typen proc info over
  struct proc pi;
  //kaller syscallet med &info som argument
  int result = getprocinfo(&pi);

  if (result < 0) {
        printf("Error: Not able to access process information!\n");
  } else {
        printf("Process ID: %d, Process state: %d\n", pi.pid, pi.state);
  }

  exit(0);

}
```

When i the run XV6 with make qemu, i only get this message: Error: Not able to access process information!. I cant make it produce any processes. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use xv6-riscv flavor?

You have several problem in you code:

- `sys_getprocinfo` prototype should be `int64 sys_getprocinfo(void)`: system calls have no parameters, they have to get them with `argaddr(int, uint64 *);`
- `pi` is defined local to `sys_getprocinfo`, but you use it as a user pointer in `copyout(...)`
- You have two `struct proc` definition: one in kernel in `proc.h` one in you `getproc.c` file. They are incompatible. You should declare a new structure with a different name in the kernel.

Comment: - Thanks for the reply. I use xv6-riscv yes.

- Regarding your last point im not sure how to tackle the struct proc definitions... I'm not sure how to solve this since struct proc is only native to the kernel and not the user space. I have tried modyfing the code, but i still dont get any input other than the Error message i have created. 

- In the kernel i use argaddr:

  struct proc *curproc = myproc();
  struct proc pi;
  uint64 addr;
 

  argaddr(0, &addr);

- And copyout like this:

if(copyout(curproc->pagetable, addr, (char*)&pi, sizeof(pi)) < 0)
        return -1;

Comment: you have to create a `struct` in the kernel that can be read from other programs, like for `#include "kernel/types.h`

Comment: `pi` must belong tthe user space. In sys call you get its address that you should pass to `copyout` : `copyout(..., ..., addr, ...)`